# Style elements if satisfy condition, AngularJS

Tags: css, angularjs, ng-style

```
<div ng-if="item.attribute == 'attribute1'">
    doSomething
</div>

<button class="button button-block button-postive waves-effect waves-button waves-light">
    Button 1
</button>
```

I want to make it so that if item.attribute == attribute1 then the color of the button is coral

```
.button.button-block, .button.button-full {

    background-color: coral;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Is this possible? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Use ng-class

```
ng-class="{ 'style': condition, 'style2' : condition2}"
```

Specifically:

```
ng-class="{ 'button-block': item.attribute == 'attribute1'}"
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-class` to accomplish this.

```
<button ng-class="{'button-block': item.attribute==attribute1}">
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way of doing it without declaring a class.

```
ng-style="item.attribute == 'attribute1' 
    && {'background-color':'red', 'color':'white'} || {'background-color':'blue', 'color':'white'}"
```